# Node.js stop function when return true/false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a bit new to Node.js and confused how I can accomplish what I aim for.

I have a function like this:

```
function Timer() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            finish();
            return true;
        }, 60000);  

        setInterval(function() {
            if (fail()) {
                return false;
            }
        }, 5000);
}
```

This function get's called once and is supposed to stop when one of the function inside it return something. Function `fail()` just rolls the dice basically and has a chance of 5% of returning `false`.

Function `finish()` is just returning `true` when the timeout is over.

How do I exit my end my function completely once it returns something somewhere?

Comment: What logic are you trying to write? A dice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to store the interval and timeout, so that you are able to use `clearInterval` / `clearTimeout` when your `end` function meets your desired condition (or the timeout finishes), and you should pass a callback to your `Timer` function so that you are able to return the value once the interval or the timeout finish:

```
function Timer(myCallback) {
    var myInterval, myTimeout;
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        finish();
        clearInterval(myInterval); //Clear the interval so that the callback won't be called again.
        myCallback(true); //Call your callback function passing true.
    }, 60000);  

    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (fail()) {
            clearInterval(myInterval); //Clear the interval so that the callback won't be called again.
            clearTimeout(myTimeout); //Clear the timeout so that the callback won't be called again.
            myCallback(false); //Call your callback function passing false.
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Now your callback will receive true/false depending which one gets called first.

```
Timer(function(condition) {
    if (condition) doSomethingWhenConditionIsTrue();
    else doSomethingWhenConditionIsFalse();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is asynchronous, it means that after `setTimeout` and `setInterval` it exits, returning no value. In JavaScript functions are designed to be asynchronous, they cannot halt the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses a [run-to-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_to_completion_scheduling) model of execution, and `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are asynchronous. This means you will have to supply the continuation logic in a function to be called at a later time. You have three options:

1. A callback
2. Promises
3. Coroutines (only if you are on a modern runtime)

Please clarify your intended logic and I will add to this answer.